# How to correctly pass an object between UIPageViewController and children

Tags: ios, ios6, uiviewcontroller, ios7, uipageviewcontroller

I have a PFObject (from Parse.com) which is loaded as a property on my UIPageViewController.

The Page VC is setup with two children controllers. Both need access to the object held on the UIPageViewController.

As the object is fairly large I feel its not best if each controller holds the same object. What is the best way to approach this?

At present only the UIPageViewController has the object. I can set the same property on the other two controllers without a problem but then I have three references to the same object. Is there a way I can keep the reference in one place/VC and link to it from the others.

Example 2 (**EDIT**)
If I have a navigation controller that has a root controller for example.
The root view controller downloads the PFObject I have in question.

If the object is then passed to the next controller with the following:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    [super prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender];

    NextViewController *VC = segue.destinationViewController;
    VC.passedObject = self.downloadedObject;
}
```

Does the above mean I am passing the reference of the object to the new controller? Or I am infact re-creating the object on the next controller.

So If I was to repeat the steps above for a group of 10-15 controllers on the navigation controller stack. Am I creating 10-15 references to the same object (already created only once) or am I re-creating this each time I pass it to a VC. Therefore having 10-15 copies of the same object.

Comment: You can use a delegate pattern so that your children have a reference to the UIPageViewController and can reference its properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have an inaccurate picture of how objects and pointers work. As you say, you would have three references to the same object. You would not have created three copies of the same object and all the data it contains. Your concerns seems to be unfounded unless there is some other aspect to it.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right. Can you confirm my further edit to the question, which explains my thoughts further please.

Comment: Can you confirm please?

Comment: You normally only create full copies of an object when you call a `copy` method on it or pass it to a property defined as using `copy`. In most cases you're just passing references to the same object with each recipient retaining that object to make sure it is not deallocated. This is efficient but can be problematic if the object is mutable. In any case don't take my word for it, experiment for yourself. Print or inspect the value of those object references in the debugger and see which ones point to the same memory address.